# Handling routes after submitting form

Tags: reactjs, forms, graphql, next.js, formik

Hello my great teachers of StackOverflow. I'm going through ben awads fullstack tutorial and am trying to add an image upload feature to create post. Looks like everything works well, inserts posts (including image) into db. However, after submitting my form, it wont send me to the home page (stays on the same page with current values inserted). It is set so that if there are no errors, route me to the homepage. Im assumming i have no errors cause the post inserts into database. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
const CreatePost: React.FC<{}> = ({}) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [createPost] = useCreatePostMutation();
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ title: "", text: "", file: null }}
        onSubmit={async (values) => {
          console.log(values);
          const { errors } = await createPost({
            variables: values,
          });
          if (!errors) {
            router.push("/");
          }
        }}
      >
        {({ isSubmitting, setFieldValue }) => (
          <Form>
            <InputField name="title" placeholder="title" label="Title" />
            <Box mt={4}>
              <InputField name="text" placeholder="text..." label="Body" />
            </Box>
            <Input
              mt={4}
              required
              type="file"
              name="file"
              id="file"
              onChange={(event) => {
                setFieldValue("file", event.currentTarget.files[0]);
              }}
            />
            <Button mt={5} type="submit" isLoading={isSubmitting}>
              create post
            </Button>
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

Comment: you need to pass validate function as props to Fomik to prevent submitting only with 2 fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `router.push` hook.

You need to pass validate function as props to Fomik to prevent submitting only with 2 fields. I have added a basic validate object. But you can use `Yup` package also. Formik will return an error object inside the form and you need to make sure form does not get submitted in error state. For that get the errors object and as you are using custom Button component pass true/false by checking if any errors exist. I added the code.

You can get more details [here](https://formik.org/docs/tutorial).

```
router.push("/home");

.....

const validate={values => {
         const errors = {};
         if (!values.title) {
           errors.email = 'Required';
         } 
         if (!values.text) {
           errors.text= 'Required';
         }
         if (!values.file) {
           errors.file= 'Required';
         }
         return errors;
       }}

<Formik
        initialValues={{ title: "", text: "", file: null }}
        validate
        onSubmit={async (values) => {

.......
{({ isSubmitting, setFieldValue, errors }) => (
..........

<Button mt={5} type="submit" isLoading={isSubmitting} isFormValid={!Object.values(errors).find(e => e)}>
              create post
            </Button>
```

Comment: OP is using Next.js which comes with a [built-in router](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router) that should be used instead of `react-router-dom`.

Comment: yea if i hit submit with just the text and title field, the form submits and routes to homepage. I feel like im missing a step with the input file field. Anyone know how i can debug it?

Comment: @HelpANoobOut you can easily find answered graphql upload problems, use search

Comment: @HelpANoobOut you need to pass validate function as props to Fomik to prevent submitting only with 2 fields.

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath yea the validation seems logical to me, ill let you know after i try

Comment: @xadm well thats the thing, is graphqlupload the issue? i dont think so cause as i said, it uploads to my database table. Probably has something to do with form validation. Which is why im not sure how to ask this question and in which category it belongs. But ill try Rajdeeps answer. Seems logical to me